# How to filter Rest api response using mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am currently working on a JSON Api project using php and mysql database I have been able to create a post and get function successfully i am trying to implement a filter feature but only able to retrieve one result even when more than one of the result has similar names Example my database contains "chuck", and "chuck Morris" when i search for "chuck" i want to be able to retrieve both names but am only getting the result with the exact name i.e "chuck" just one result 
Here is my code for the search function

```
public function read_singleName() {
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name . " WHERE name = ?";
    $obj = $this->conn->prepare($sql_query);
    $obj->bind_param("s", $this->name);
    $obj->execute();
    $data = $obj->get_result();
    return $data->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Here is the code to display the results

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET"){

  $artist_name = isset($_GET['name']) ? strval($_GET['name']) : "";

  if(!empty($some_name)){

    $some->name = $some_name;
    $some_data = $some->read_singleName();

    if(!empty($some_data)){
      http_response_code(200);
      echo json_encode(array(
          "status" => 1,
          "data" => $some_data
      ));
    } else{
      http_response_code(500);
      echo json_encode(array(
        "status" => 0,
        "message" => "Name Not Found"
      ));
    }   
    }   

} else{
    http_response_code(503);
    echo "Access Denied";
    echo json_encode(array(
        "status" => 000,
        "message" => "Failed"
    ));
}
```

Comment: With SQL, you're going to want to use the ``LIKE`` operator and not ``=``. For instance, a sample query would be, ``SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name LIKE '%chuck%';``

Comment: @Damian is right to use LIKE not = 
check the demo - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g7Rp3a3eAsFQUjNqmNAGo/0

Comment: Code is fine but still the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure what `$this->conn` is but I think you should call `fetch_assoc()` in a while loop until there are no more records

```
while($record = $data->fetch_assoc()){
    // do something with $record
}
```

Also the query should be like this:  `SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name . " WHERE name LIKE '%chuck%'`

Comment: Thank alot but am still getting the same result but can you help me with the full code of where i should use the while loop

Comment: Replace this line: `return $data->fetch_assoc();` with this `return $data->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Bless You Thanks a billion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIKE`, not `=`.

When you do this:

```
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name . " WHERE name = ?";
```

You will only get exact matches.

What you need is this:

```
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name . " WHERE name LIKE ?";
```

And then use `%` characters as wild cards.

This will find everything that begins with "chuck"

```
WHERE name LIKE 'chuck%'
```

Another example where "chuck" can be anywhere.

```
WHERE name LIKE '%chuck%'
```